# Retrieving result from celery worker constantly

Tags: python, database, celery

I have an web app in which I am trying to use celery to load background tasks from a database. I am currently loading the database upon request, but would like to load the tasks on an hourly interval and have them work in the background. I am using flask and am coding in python.I have redis running as well.

So far using celery I have gotten the worker to process the task and the beat to send the tasks to the worker on an interval. But I want to retrieve the results[a dataframe or query] from the worker and if the result is not ready then it should load the previous result of the worker.

Any ideas on how to do this?

**Edit**

I am retrieving the results from a database using sqlalchemy and I am rendering the results in a webpage. I have my homepage which has all the various links which all lead to different graphs which I want to be loaded in the background so the user does not have to wait long loading times.

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by "load background tasks from a database"? or "loading the database"? it would help to provide the best approach to solve your needs. Generally, you dont get result from worker, worker is executing tasks and store the results in the backend... so from your terminology it is a bit hard to tell what you should do.

Comment: @creativeChips do you retrieve the results from redis server?

Comment: I personally got mongo as backend, and I indeed query for the results directly from the mongo collection, when needed.
I took a chance hoping I get your usecase, and posted an answer ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Celery [Task](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#tasks) is being executed by a Worker, and it's Result is being stored in the [Celery Backend](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results).

If I get you correctly, then I think you got few options:

1. [Ignore the result](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#ignore-results-you-don-t-want) of the graph-loading-task, store what ever you need, as a side effect of the task, in your database. When needed, query for the most recent result in that database. If the DB is Redis, you may find [ZADD](http://redis.io/commands/ZADD) and [ZRANGE](http://redis.io/commands/ZRANGE) suitable. This way you'll get the new if available, or the previous if not.
2. You can look for the [result of a task if you provide it's id](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult). You can do this when you want to find out the status, something like (where `celery` is the Celery app): `result = celery.AsyncResult(<the task id>)`
3. Use [callback](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks) to update farther when new result is ready.
4. Let a background thread [wait](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.wait) for the AsyncResult, or [native_join](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.ResultSet.join_native), which is supported with Redis, and update accordingly (not recommended)

I personally used option #1 in similar cases (using MongoDB) and found it to be very maintainable and flexible. But possibly, due the nature of your UI, option #3 will more suitable for you needs.